# How to call a Assemly-Function in a standalone c#-script

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple c#-script which looks like this:

```
<script language="c#" runat="server">
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var t = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().TotalVirtualMemory;
}
</script>
```

In a normal project within Visual Studio, i would have to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll, and everything works.

How can I achieve this in a standalone-script as shown above?

Comment: I'm fairly sure your references go in to the solution/project file and are contained within the resulting DLL (even though there is no other source code). Then, when the site is loaded, the DLL is read loading the references and then it loads/executes your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep - as Frank V says, you add the reference to the project containing the page.

Having a proper or 'full' code-behind file (page.aspx.cs) and putting your code in there is no different to what you are doing: they both get compiled to the same thing.

The reason not to use a code-behind file would be if there is minimal code (and not a lot of markup on the page either) so that putting the two in one file is not confusing.

The reason to use a code-behind file is to separate viewing data (the page) from processing it (the code-behind); in tghe long term such separation leads to fewer bugs.

Comment: That's true, i'm using no code behind for this script, because this page is used to return a simple json, consumed by another application.
Sadly, there is no built-in function in .NET to gather the amount of the installed RAM...

Comment: "Sadly, there is no built-in function in .NET to gather the amount of the installed RAM." I have no idea what you are talking about. This has nothing to do with the question you posed. (It is also a useless piece of information - in 32bit windows you have approx 3GB available to your process; in 64Bit you have terrabytes..)

Comment: Ok, sorry for the obscurity in my comment.I'm saying this, because i need to read the installed amount of intalled RAM.

Comment: So open another question asking how to do this. Before you do that, check out pinvoke.net, after searching for a windows function that will give you the answer.

Comment: I checked out pinvoke.net and managed to obtain all my necessary information (with the GlobalMemoryStatusEx(...) function in Kernel32.dll)